# Error:Failed to perform cache operation (cache is stopped), after service is idle for hours

Tags: caching, ignite, illegalstateexception

When service was idle for an hour or two, it gives the following exception. But it was working fine earlier and this only happens when the service is idle for a long time period. It works after restarting, but that is not a solution as I need to move this to production.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: class org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.CacheStoppedException: Failed to perform cache operation (cache is stopped): ACCOUNT_CACHE
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheGateway.enter(GridCacheGateway.java:165)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GatewayProtectedCacheProxy.onEnter(GatewayProtectedCacheProxy.java:1584)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GatewayProtectedCacheProxy.query(GatewayProtectedCacheProxy.java:382)
    at com.prasadct.processor.datastore.IgniteCacheHandler.executeFieldQueryForMap(IgniteCacheHandler.java:642)
    at com.prasadct.processor.dao.ipml.AccountStatusDAOImpl.getAccountStatusCountFromDC(AccountStatusDAOImpl.java:80)
    at com.prasadct.processor.service.impl.AccountProcessingService.processAccountReconcile(AccountProcessingService.java:113)
    at com.prasadct.processor.service.impl.AccountProcessingService.reconcileCountProcess(AccountProcessingService.java:102)
    at com.prasadct.processor.service.impl.AccountProcessingService.process(AccountProcessingService.java:87)
    at com.prasadct.processor.service.impl.AccountProcessingService.process(AccountProcessingService.java:39)
    at com.prasadct.processor.service.AbstractOperationService.executeService(AbstractOperationService.java:116)
    at com.prasadct.processor.service.AbstractOperationService.execute(AbstractOperationService.java:66)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor105.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:171)
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:120)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.support.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper$HandlerMethod.invoke(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:1087)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.support.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.invokeHandlerMethod(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:584)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.support.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.processInternal(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:473)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.support.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.process(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:317)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.processMessage(MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.java:104)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.ServiceActivatingHandler.handleRequestMessage(ServiceActivatingHandler.java:93)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:123)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:169)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.MessageHandlerChain.lambda$configureChain$0(MessageHandlerChain.java:124)
    at org.springframework.messaging.MessageChannel.send(MessageChannel.java:45)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:187)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:166)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:109)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:415)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:334)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:225)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:129)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:169)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.MessageHandlerChain.handleMessageInternal(MessageHandlerChain.java:110)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:162)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:115)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:133)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.access$000(UnicastingDispatcher.java:53)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher$1.run(UnicastingDispatcher.java:114)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.lambda$execute$0(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:57)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Caused by: org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.CacheStoppedException: Failed to perform cache operation (cache is stopped): ACCOUNT_CACHE
        ... 45 common frames omitted

Comment: Are you sure you don't see "local node SEGMENTED" before that happens? Does the cache actually exist at this point?

Comment: @alamar How can I know about that? From logs, I can't find anything similar.

Comment: It should be in the logs. What are the events leading to this error? Anything in the logs before you see that?